# Why does returning the length of a local variable in a reduce function throw an error?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions, string-length

Currently doing this challenge: https://www.codewars.com/kata/shortest-word/train/javascript

Find the shortest length of word in a string.

This works:

```
function findShort(s){
  return s.split(' ').reduce((a, b) => b.length < a.length ? b : a).length;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
function findShort(s){
  return s.split(' ').reduce((a, b) => b.length < a.length ? b.length : a.length);
}
```

Any idea why I can't return the length of a or b even though they should be strings? I'm clearly missing something here...

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to write your own logic to find the minimum of a list--`Math.min` already does that. Try `Math.min(...s.split(' ').map(({length}) => length)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value from the `.reduce()` callback is the value that's passed successively for each invocation of the callback. If the first iteration of the callback returns just the `.length` value, then that **number** will be passed to the second iteration. When that happens, your code will attempt to find a `.length` property on a number, which won't exist, and you end up juggling an `undefined` value.

So, in the first (working) version of the code, the callback is first invoked with `a` being the first word of the split string and `b` being the second. It returns either `a` or `b`. Then the callback is invoked again with the result of that first call as `a` and the third word as `b`. The process repeats until the last word is passed as `b` and the final string is returned. Then, after `.reduce()` is finished, the code grabs the `.length` of that shortest string.

In the second (non-working) version, the first invocation is as in the working version, with the first word as `a` and the second as `b`. The callback returns the length of the shorter word. Thus, on the second invocation of the callback, `a` is a number (the previously returned shorter length) and `b` is the third word. Accessing `a.length` will be `undefined`, so the comparison will be `false` and the function will return `a.length`, which is `undefined`. On the third invocation of the callback, `a` will therefore be `undefined`, and the attempt to access `a.length` will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now! I was too focused on the .length I forgot how reduce works in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to convert the array of strings first to an array of numbers, so the reduce operation can just operate on the numbers:

```
s.split(' ').map(x => x.length).reduce((a, b) => b < a ? b : a);
```